# Difference between $\forall n\in\mathbb N$ and $\bigcap_{i = 1}^{\infty}$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Really confused about the difference between $\forall n\in\mathbb N$ and $\bigcap_{i=1}^\infty$.

In *Understanding Analysis*, I quote from Exercise 1.2.13. that

> It is tempting to appeal to induction to conclude $$(\bigcup_{i = 1}^\infty A_i)^c = \bigcap_{i=1}^\infty A_i^c\ \ ,$$
> but induction does not apply here. Induction is used to prove that a particular statement holds for every value of $n\in\mathbb N$, but this does not imply the validity of the infinite case.

Have done some research on that for a while and understood that eventually the fact that I can point out a $n\in\mathbb N$ means that $n$ is finite. Hence, it cannot apply to the infinite case.

Yes, I understand the rationale. But if $\forall n \in\mathbb N$ doesn't work, then what works on proving infinite case?

Just as I feel comfy about the difference, the confusion is again brought up by the book and I indirectly quote in the following, in hopes of making it as short as possible:

The nested interval property assumes that each $I_n$ contains $I_{n+1}$. They are a nested sequence of closed intervals defined as such. $I_n = [a_n, b_n] = \{x\in\mathbb R : a_n\leq x \leq b_n\}$.

The proof focuses on finding a single real number x that belongs to all $I_n$ and it argues it is $\sup A$.

In the proof, it said $x\in I_n$, for every choice of $n\in\mathbb N$. Hence, $x\in \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty I_n$ and the intersection is not empty.

Let me know if the missed out details are needed. However, my point is just that:

1. Why in the infinite de morgan's rule $\forall n\in\mathbb N$ doesn't apply to $\infty$
2. Why in the nested interval property $\forall n\in\mathbb N$ applies to $\infty$

Comment: Maybe a counterexample could help to understand: the intervals $U_n = (-\frac1n,\frac1n) \subset \mathbb R$ are all open. Moreover, $U_n \cap U_m = U_{\min(n,m)}$ is again open. So every intersection of a finite number of the $U_n$ is again open. But if you take the intersection of *all* the $U_n$, you end up with $\{0\}$, which is not open.

Comment: The nested interval property does not use induction.

Comment: You say you're quoting, but there is no indication of which parts of what you write are quoted.

Comment: I wouldn't use induction in the finite case; rather I would prove it the same as as in the infinite case. What I would do would not depend on whether the index set is finite or infinite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\forall n\in\Bbb N$ **never** applies to $\infty$, because $\infty$ is not an element of $\Bbb N$. In the nested interval theorem **there is no** $I_\infty$. What we know is that $x\in I_n$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$, and therefore by definition $n$ is in the intersection of the sets $I_n$. You could call this intersection $I_\infty$ if you wanted to do so, but that would be an arbitrary choice altogether independent of the induction argument involving the sets $I_n$; you could just as well call it George. (Many years ago a friend of mine did in fact publish a paper about a mathematical object that he named George.)

As for De Morgan’s law, one proves it for arbitrary families of sets simply by showing that each side of the proposed identity is a subset of the other. This is done for arbitrary indexed families of sets [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/207570/infinite-demorgan-laws) and in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3622592/de-morgans-formulas-set-theory/3622616#3622616) (and probably other places at MSE as well). The proof does not depend on the theorem for finite families of sets and does not involve any kind of induction.

Comment: LOL about George

Comment: @J.W.Tanner: We all got a kick out of that one. It’s a topological space inspired by R.H. Bing’s well-known (in some circles) Example G, and *George* also happens to be my friend’s middle name.

Comment: In particular, when I see pishy things like $\cap_{i=1}^{\infty}$, should I first apply induction then check whether infinite case holds?

Comment: Or should I put it in this way, if $\infty$ is not necessarily referring to $P(\infty)$ and may refer to $\forall n\in N$, why in first place do people not differentiate the 2 clearly? Though I know natural number set is infinite either. But it is confusing, isn't it?

Comment: @AndesLam: I’m afraid that I honestly don’t understand what it is that you find confusing. The $\infty$ in $\bigcap_{i=1}^\infty A_i$ does not mean that there is a set $A_\infty$. You could just as well write $\bigcap_{i\ge 1}A_i$ or $\bigcap\{A_i:i\in\Bbb Z^+\}$. Similarly, writing $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ instead of $\sum_{n\ge 1}a_n$ for an infinite series does not mean that there is an $a_\infty$.

Answer (score 3):

De Morgan's Rule does happen to work for infinite sets. But this cannot be proven by inducting on the finite version of De Morgan's Rule, since induction is a tool for proving that a statement is true for an arbitrarily large value of $n$ (but $n$ is still finite).

As for the intersection of a countably infinite number of sets, this follows from the definition. We say that $x \in \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty I_n$ iff $x \in I_n$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$.